# Merge two std::sets

Tags: c++, stl

I need to merge two sets into a resultant set on basis of one member variable qty if the prices are same. In the below example my resultant set s3 should contain:

Price : 100
Qty : 40

Price : 200
Qty : 60

Please note qty above is a sum of qty in both the sets respective when the price is same.

My question is how do I construct the set s3 below:

Please guide me with the same.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PriceLevel
{
public:
    int price;
    int qty;

    PriceLevel(int _price, int _qty)
    {
        price = _price;
        qty = _qty;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const PriceLevel &p, const PriceLevel &q);
};

bool operator<(const PriceLevel &p, const PriceLevel &q)
{
    if(p.price < q.price)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<PriceLevel> s1;
    std::set<PriceLevel> s2;

    PriceLevel p1(100,10);
    PriceLevel p2(200,20);

    PriceLevel p3(100,30);
    PriceLevel p4(200,40);

    s1.insert(p1);
    s1.insert(p2);

    s2.insert(p3);
    s2.insert(p4);

    std::set<PriceLevel> s3;

    set<PriceLevel>::iterator it = s3.begin();

    // How should I Initialize s3

    for(; it != s3.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "Price: " << it->price << endl;
        cout << "Qty : " << it->qty << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a `std::set`? A `std::map` seems a much more natural fit for this use-case.

Comment: Yes. It's a legacy code which uses set and I need to merge it. I cannot change it to make it as a map.

Comment: Can you do the merge using a temporary `std::map` and then construct the final `std::set` from it? Not the most efficient solution but probably the simplest one to go and still reasonable in the overhead.

Comment: I thought of that but taking an extra map would be a an overhead and addition to space complexity. I was trying if std::set_union or std::merge can work, but could not find a substantial solution.

Comment: Also please note for simplicity reason i have added only two fields in PrivelLevel class, but infact there are much more than 2 fields(around 10) in PriceLevel class. Hence Map using map may be cumbersome here.

Comment: I don't think there is a perfect solution. You have an inappropriate data structure for the problem at hand so you shouldn't expect optimal efficiency. The additional fields shouldn't be a problem, as long as you have a single key. I wouldn't worry too much about the overhead until I've benchmarked it.

Comment: Why are you posting a duplicate of your previous post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that both source sets contain exactly the same prices, you can use the binary version of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

If they might contain unequal data, you'll have to do it manually, like this:

```
std::set<PriceLevel> s3;

// How should I Initialize s3
std::set<PriceLevel>::iterator 
    first1 = s1.begin(),
    last1 = s1.end(),
    first2 = s2.begin(),
    last2 = s2.end();
while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
    if (first1->price < first2->price) {        
        s3.insert(*first1++);
    }
    else if (first1->price > first2->price) {
        s3.insert(*first2++);
    }
    else {
        s3.insert(PriceLevel(first1->price, first1->qty + first2->qty));
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
    }
}
while (first1 != last1) {
     s3.insert(*first1++);
}
while (first2 != last2) {
     s3.insert(*first2++);
}
```

This is best put in an extra function.

[View on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/Fqc8Lo)

If you *only* need those prices in the result set which existed in *both* source sets, it is a bit simpler:

```
while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
    if (first1->price < first2->price) {        
        ++first1;
    }
    else if (first1->price > first2->price) {
        ++first2;
    }
    else {
        s3.insert(PriceLevel(first1->price, first1->qty + first2->qty));
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge two sets with just two lines

```
#include <set>

template <typename _Ty>
std::set<_Ty> merge(const std::set<_Ty> &x, const std::set<_Ty> &y) const
{
    std::set<_Ty> merged = x; //initial merged set from x
    merged.insert(y.begin(), y.end()); //add contents of y to merged

    return move(merged);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but the use of `auto` and `-> std::set<_Ty>` feels gratuitous.  Just write the return type directly instead of using `auto`.  `auto` is for cases where the compiler deduces the return type, not for cases when you're writing it explicitly.  Also, you have no `return` statement.

Comment: Is the use of `std::move` here necessary?  I'm still learning all the details of move semantics, but I thought it was unnecessary to `std::move` when you are returning a value directly from a function.  In this case, even return value optimization from C++98 should have done the equivalent of a move.

Answer (score 1):

`set` is not an appropriate data structure for your application here. Consider using a `map<int, int>` instead:

```
map<int, int> p1, p2, p3; // map price -> quantity

p1[100] = 10;
p1[200] = 20;

p2[100] = 30;
p2[200] = 40;

p3 = p1;
for(auto &i : p2) {
    p3[i.first] += i.second;
}

// Now p3[100]=40 and p3[200]=60.
```

---

You can also use a `set` kind of like a `map` using `set::find`:

```
s3 = s1;
for(auto &i : s2) {
    auto it = s3.find(i);
    if(it == s3.end()) {
        s3.insert(i);
    } else {
        it->qty += i.qty;
    }
}
```

For this to work, you will have to declare `qty` as a `mutable int`, so that it can be modified even if the `PriceLevel` struct is `const` (since elements of a `set` are `const`).

If you can't make the variable `mutable`, then you can try removing the existing set element and then adding a new, merged element.

Comment: I cannot change it to make it as a map as its a legacy code. I need to fit in this to a set as I mentioned above. Map would have been pretty straight forward though. Taking into an extra map would be a an overhead and addition to space complexity. I was trying if std::set_union or std::merge can work.

Comment: You may want to give a more realistic example of your code, then. Besides, there is certainly no standard library way to perform the merge as described - you will have to write some looping code to do it.

Comment: Also please note for simplicity reason i have added only two fields in PrivelLevel class, but infact there are much more than 2 fields(around 10) in PriceLevel class. Hence Map using map may be cumbersome here.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are using some fields as a key and some other fields as a value, and you want to "merge" by updating values of corresponding keys. This _is_ a perfect application for a map. You can use a set like a map by doing a lookup with `set::find`, though, so that might point you to a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially trying to use a set as a map AND merge values with equal keys. You will need to roll your own result (not to mention that it really isn't advisable...). Here is something to get you started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class PriceLevel
{
public:
    int price;
    int qty;

    PriceLevel() {
        price = 0;
        qty = 0;
    }

    PriceLevel(int _price, int _qty)
    {
        price = _price;
        qty = _qty;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const PriceLevel &p, const PriceLevel &q);

    //Compares two PriceLevel objects and merges their values if their keys are the same.
    //Return value is a std::pair that
    //denotes if the compare was successful and the result is meaningful.        
    static std::pair<bool, PriceLevel> merge_equal(const PriceLevel& p, const PriceLevel& q) {
        std::pair<bool, PriceLevel> result;
        result.first = false;
        if(p.price == q.price) {
            result.first = true;
            result.second.price = p.price;
            result.second.qty = p.qty + q.qty;
        }
        return result;
    }

};

bool operator<(const PriceLevel &p, const PriceLevel &q)
{
    if(p.price < q.price)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<PriceLevel> s1;
    std::set<PriceLevel> s2;

    PriceLevel p1(100,10);
    PriceLevel p2(200,20);

    PriceLevel p3(100,30);
    PriceLevel p4(200,40);

    s1.insert(p1);
    s1.insert(p2);

    s2.insert(p3);
    s2.insert(p4);

    std::set<PriceLevel> s3;

    //Just in case...the world may explode otherwise.
    if(s1.size() == s2.size()) {

        for(const auto& pl1 : s1) {
            for(const auto& pl2 : s2) {
                //Only insert valid values.
                auto r = PriceLevel::merge_equal(pl1, pl2);
                if(r.first) s3.insert(r.second);
            }
        }

        for(auto it = s3.begin(); it != s3.end(); it++) {
            cout << "Price: " << it->price << endl;
            cout << "Qty : " << it->qty << endl;
        }
    }
}
```